# Is there any method to script OBS Studio with global hotkeys?

Tags: obs-studio

I'm wanting to use OBS Studio for recording videos. It has notions like "Scenes", is there anyway for me to transition between two screens using hotkey entry in i3 or the like? I want them to trigger when the window is not in focus and it seems currently they only trigger when the window is in focus (receiving keyboard events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made this into a [feature request](https://ideas.obsproject.com/posts/1280/allow-scripting-or-message-sending-to-the-obs-client), because there is not currently a method to do what I want.

One method seems to be using the [`obs-websocket` plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-websocket-remote-control-obs-studio-from-websockets.466/). Another method is [manually forwarding the keystrokes from within Xorg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627403/3285).