# How can I forward global hotkeys to a program that only listens when the window is in focus?

Tags: x11, i3, xdotool

Let's say there is a program (like OBS, Chrome, or Discord) that accepts hotkeys (to open, save, print, etc) how can I forward a global hotkey like those configured in i3 to a program that only local accepts events targeted to the window.

For example, let's say I want to target a running version of Chrome for Printing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). How can I set up a hotkey such that Chrome will open up the printing dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) if it's not in focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by,

1. Finding both,

   - Your current active window. (`src`)
   - The target window. (`dst`).
2. Scripting,

   1. bounce to the `dst`
   2. a submission of the key
   3. a bounce back to the `src`

To find the window that's open you can use `xdotool`,

```
src=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
dst=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "Chromium")
```

And then to send it the proper key you can use,

```
export key="Ctrl+P"
xdotool windowfocus --sync "$dst" key "$key" windowfocus --sync "$src"
```